# Jenkins - Source Code Management, credential error

Tags: jenkins, credentials

I have a repo on Bitbucket I'm trying to connect to my Jenkins instance. 
Not taking the SSH key approach here but plain id/password since communications will take place in SSL.

(1) I double checked the id/password on both BitBucket and on Jenkins entry. I tried both scope of both Global and System.

(2) I added a hook on Bitbucket pointing to my Jenkins instance.

(3) Installed the proper bitbucket plugin on Jenkins.

But I'm keep on getting

```
     "Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://bitbucket.org/id/demo HEAD" 
and 
"Failed to connect to repository : Could not init /tmp/hudson4950610074146191608tmp"
```

I searched what both errors mean but I can't determine whether this is a credential issue.

I'm out of clue as to how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have install git on the Jenkins server, and check if you have set the git executable path in the Jenkins configuration

Comment: More specifically go to 'Manage Jenkins' -> 'Configure System' and check the 'Path to Git executable' field. Making sure that git was installed and that that path was correct fixed my "Failed to connect to repository : Could not init /tmp/hudson123...123tmp" error.

Comment: on Jenkins ver. 2.7.4, the setting property of (Path to Git executable) is now in Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> Git -> Git Installations -> Path to Git executable.

Answer (score 1):

Upon struggling for days, turns out the private key Jenkins was using had permission set incorrectly.
User name and keys must match.

Comment: SndLt, I am also getting the same error when connecting to bitbucket from jenkins. I didnt understand your answer. Can you please elaborate on the above answer.
Thanks,
Vaibhav